# Box shadow on div with html/css/scss

Tags: html, css, sass, shadow, card

[Card example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo00r.png)

Hello all,  i'd like to replicate those shadows underneath some card divs using html/css or scss. I was thinking of some kind of loop (scss) adding several divs on to another with just a px offset between it's previous div both in x and y. Not sure how to achieve that.
You guys have any suggestions on how you would do it?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Your plan to add that many divs is... not great. It will be a heavy page trying to do that. Maybe something like this could work, though the overflows are a bit of an issue...

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  background: teal;
  overflow: hidden;
}
main {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
main div {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
main:before,
main:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: black;
}
main:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
main:after {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
  transform: skewY(45deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
</main>
```